# How can I copy and modify text from one element to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, clone

i am new to JQuery and the question I am going to ask is very simple for most of you.

I need to create a paragraph tag with id "original", and with the content "This is the original text." I want to create an empty paragraph tag with id "clone".

I want to Write a script that stores the value of the '#original' text in a variable, replaces the word 'original' with the word 'cloned' in another variable, and places that value in '#clone'.

Result: There will be two paragraphs, one saying "This is the original text." and another saying "This is the cloned text."

Please explain how can i do this as simple as you can :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us some code that you're already trying out.

Comment: A little jquery research goes a long way.

Comment: i don't have any idea how to do it. I'm totally 0 in it. If i knew why would I ask the question. Thank you for giving negative mark for asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to make use of the jQuery [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function which will allow you to store the text content into a variable.

```
var originalText = $("#original").text();
```

Then you can manipulate that variable like so.

```
var modifiedText = originalText.replace("original", "cloned");
```

Then, using the same .text() function, you can write text into the cloned element.

```
$("#clone").text(modifiedText);
```

### **Here's a working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DLeGa/

Of course, you could do this all in one line as well.

```
$("#clone").text($("#original").text().replace("original", "cloned"));
```

Or you could turn it into a reusable function.

```
function cloneText(srcSelector, destSelector, stringToReplace, replaceWith) {
  var text = $(srcSelector).text();
  var modifiedText = text.replace(stringToReplace, replaceWith);
  $(destSelector).text(modifiedText);    
}

// Usage
cloneText("#original", "#clone", "original", "cloned");
```

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

 var originalText = $("#original").text();

 var modifiedText = originalText.replace("original", "cloned");

 $("#clone").text(modifiedText);

});

  </script>


 <p id="original"> This is the original text.</p>

    <p id="clone"> </p>


I don't know how to display clone text?

Comment: Sorry my comments are messed up... don't know how to write in proper way :( I am sorry for that

Comment: The code you pasted into the comments works perfectly. See this jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/DLeGa/

Comment: Thanks Jessegavin, I was not using JQuery 1.9.1 so that's why it was not working but now its working fine after you showed the example. Thank you so much.